# Optimized size and dpi for Android app images

Tags: android, image, memory, drawable

My app has a background image and I would like to create different files of it for the sake of multiple screen support.

I sent this link (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for a graphic designer but he asked me the dimensions in pixels that I want the images to be created with.

Considering that I have a graphic designer in my team and I don’t want to use a code to optimize the images loaded in memory (I only want to place the images in the correct folders for small, normal, large and xlarge screens), what are the most **optimized** size and dpi settings to generate it?

We are working with PNG files.

For the dpi we are following this:

- ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
- mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
- hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
- xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

But for the dimensions I could only find this, which is in dp and not in px:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 dp = 1 px on 160dpi screen.
But your best bet for screen dimens is to look here
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing
and scroll down to where is shows the screen dimens in pixels (eg: 1920x1080) (Table 3)
Then check which ones you need most by looking at the chart 
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens

but the first link will give you the most used screen dimensions in use by Android devices.